# Declare variable outside of javascript file and use it in file

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, declare

so i am declaring a variable inside of a .php file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/script/jscript_pages.js">
        var templatePath = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>";
    </script>
```

But i want to use the variable templatePath inside of jscript_pages.js but when i do it like this my console says: Uncaught ReferenceError...

I hope someone can help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of a script element is alternative content to use if the browser doesn't support `src`, it isn't a script to run before running the external script.

Use two script elements.

```
<script>
    var templatePath = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>";
</script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/script/jscript_pages.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable before you reference it in script.

```
<script>
    var templatePath = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/script/jscript_pages.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Quentin said, it's either/or in a single tag.

In concept, you can do what you're looking for by having two script tags

```
<script type='text/javascript'>      
            var templatePath = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>";
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/script/jscript_pages.js"></script>
```

But, in practice what's usually better (for testing, portability, etc) is for your script file to just define functions and then have your on-page scripts (if you have them) call those functions and apply the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In this setup, your function `bloginfo('template_directory');` should return a $GLOBALS variable.